# SQL - Character-separated values into columns and values

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, regexp-substr, csv

I have a dataset where the registry of a column in a table looks like this:

```
CATEG_1¤0000¿CATEG_2¤00000¿CATEG_3¤aaaabbb and so on
```

and the next registry could look like this:

```
CATEG_2¤0000¿CATEG_9¤aaaaabbbb¿CATEG_15¤000000
```

Let's call a portion of text between the ¿ sign a "case". Each registry has different number of cases

There is a large set of categories that belong to other columns in different tables (within the same database). For example:

Category 2 is in Table1 and Table3
Category 3 is in Table2 and Table1

What I intend to do is build a query that identifies each column name with the portion before each "¤",  and the actual value as the portion after the ¤ symbol, but before a ¿.

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: This has been answered a million times.  Search for info on parsing name value pairs. By the way, what's the question?  Give it a try first, then ask about issues you may have.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: Sorry for asking @Gary_W , I thought that's what this site is for, not for assuming I haven't tried solving this on my own before asking here (one of the tags is "regexp-substr" because it's how I've been trying to get on with this - this is my first post for a reason). I have been working with SQL for about 3 months, so give me a break and try bringing something constructive, other than diminishing rushed opinions.

The term actually helped me search for more information. thanks for that.